# Embedding Subplots in wxPython

Tags: wxpython, matplotlib, python-2.5

I am using Python Active version 2.5(32 bits). I am facing a problem in doing subplotting in wxPython. In the program when I click 1st button the both subplots work fine but when I click on 2nd button, the overlap occurs in 1st subplot while the 2nd subplot works well according to program. Moreover, when I again click the 1st button then 1st subplot doesn't change while the 2nd subplot change according to program. You can observe it when you run the program. All I want is to remove the overlapping problem and the statically nature of 1st subplot i.e. by clicking again the 1st or 2nd button, the 1st subplot should change like 2nd subplot.

One more thing: how to plot a data against date? Python gives error as Python doesn't convert date into float while for plotting I think it is necessary to convert data into float.

Waiting for a positive response.

```
    import sys,os,csv
    import numpy as N
    import wx
    import matplotlib
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import \
        FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigCanvas, \
        NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar
    class FinalProject(wx.Frame):
        title = ' FYP Project '
        def __init__(self):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, self.title)
            self.create_menu()
            self.create_status_bar()
            self.create_main_panel()
        def create_menu(self):
            self.menubar = wx.MenuBar()
            menu_file = wx.Menu()
            m_expt = menu_file.Append(-1, "&Save plot\tCtrl-S", "Save plot to file")
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_save_plot, m_expt)
            menu_file.AppendSeparator()
            m_exit = menu_file.Append(-1, "E&xit\tCtrl-X", "Exit")
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_exit, m_exit)
            self.menubar.Append(menu_file, "&File")
            self.SetMenuBar(self.menubar)
        def create_main_panel(self):
            self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
            self.dpi = 100
            self.fig = Figure((9.5, 5.0), dpi=self.dpi)
            self.canvas = FigCanvas(self.panel, -1, self.fig)
            self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
            self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
            self.drawbutton1 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Trial Version 1")
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_draw_button1, self.drawbutton1)
            self.drawbutton2 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Trial Version 2")
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_draw_button2, self.drawbutton2)
            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas)
            self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            self.vbox.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
            self.vbox.Add(self.toolbar, 0, wx.EXPAND)
            self.vbox.AddSpacer(10)
            self.hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            flags = wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL
            self.hbox.Add(self.drawbutton1, 0, border=3, flag=flags)
            self.hbox.Add(self.drawbutton2, 0, border=3, flag=flags)
            self.vbox.Add(self.hbox, 0, flag = wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.TOP)
            self.panel.SetSizer(self.vbox)
            self.vbox.Fit(self)
        def create_status_bar(self):
            self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        def on_draw_button1(self, event):
            self.axes.clear()
            i = N.arange(0,4,1)
            q = i
            w = N.arange(-4,0,1)
            self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
            self.axes.plot(q,i,'red')
            self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
            self.axes.plot(w,i,'yellow')
            self.canvas.draw()
        def on_draw_button2(self, event):
            self.axes.clear()
            a = [0,1,2,3,4,]
            b = [5.5,4.5,3.5,2.5,1.5]
            c = [7.5,2.5,4,6.8,10.6]
            self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
            self.axes.plot(b,a,'purple')
            self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
            self.axes.plot(c,a,'black')
            self.canvas.draw()
        def on_save_plot(self, event): 
            file_choices = "PNG (*.png)|*.png"

            dlg = wx.FileDialog(
                self, 
                message="Save plot as...",
                defaultDir=os.getcwd(),
                defaultFile="plot.png",
                wildcard=file_choices,
                style=wx.SAVE)

            if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                path = dlg.GetPath()
                self.canvas.print_figure(path, dpi=self.dpi)
                self.flash_status_message("Saved to %s" % path)

        def on_exit(self, event):
            self.Destroy()
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = wx.PySimpleApp()
        app.frame = FinalProject()
        app.frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
        del app
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a few fixes. You need to differentiate between the two axes you are using. You do not need to create them everytime, just to clear them, and then plot each line in its corresponding axes.

The following changes make you code work as expected:

```
def create_main_panel(self):
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
    self.dpi = 100
    self.fig = Figure((9.5, 5.0), dpi=self.dpi)
    self.canvas = FigCanvas(self.panel, -1, self.fig)
    self.axes1 = self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)            # <--
    self.axes2 = self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)            # <--
    self.drawbutton1 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Trial Version 1")
    ............................

def on_draw_button1(self, event):
    self.axes1.clear()                           # <--
    self.axes2.clear()                           # <--
    i = N.arange(0,4,1)
    q = i
    w = N.arange(-4,0,1)
    #self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)     # <-- delete
    self.axes1.plot(q,i,'red')                   # <--
    #self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)     # <-- delete
    self.axes2.plot(w,i,'yellow')                # <--
    self.canvas.draw()
def on_draw_button2(self, event):
    self.axes1.clear()                           # <--
    self.axes2.clear()                           # <--
    a = [0,1,2,3,4,]
    b = [5.5,4.5,3.5,2.5,1.5]
    c = [7.5,2.5,4,6.8,10.6]
    #self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)     # <-- delete
    self.axes1.plot(b,a,'purple')                # <--
    #self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)     # <-- delete
    self.axes2.plot(c,a,'black')                 # <--
    self.canvas.draw()
```